# Created an ingress, not getting address from Metallb address range

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, rke2

I'm trying to set up a bare-metal kubernetes (RKE2) cluster. I installed metallb following the instructions in the documentation using helm by creating an IP address pool and l2 advertisement.

```
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: IPAddressPool
metadata:
  name: service-pool
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  addresses:
  - 192.169.5.0/24
```

I am creating an ingress for my deployment but instead of taking an IP address from the pool range, when I do `kubectl get ing -n  it shows the IP addresses of the nodes in the cluster.

```
NAME          CLASS   HOSTS                      ADDRESS                                 PORTS   AGE
ingress-web   nginx   example.com   192.169.0.10,192.169.0.11
```

What am I doing wrong? The local network the cluster is connected to is in the `192.169.0.0/16` range.

I've been able to create a nginx deployment and service to expose it, this got an external IP which I was able to use for curling requests successfully.